# in Ipython a function named display gives me an error

Tags: ipython, vpython, glowscript

```
# Kepler's Laws.py

# plots the orbit of a planet in an eccentric orbit to illustrate
# the sweeping out of equal areas in equal times, with sun at focus
# The eccentricity of the orbit is random and determined by the initial velocity
# program uses normalised units (G =1)

# program by Peter Borcherds, University of Birmingham, England

from vpython import *
from random import random
from IPython import display
import pandas as pd

def MonthStep(time, offset=20, whole=1):  # mark the end of each "month"
    global ccolor  # have to make it global, since label uses it before it is updated
    if whole:
        Ltext = str(int(time * 2 + dt))  # end of 'month', printing twice time gives about 12 'months' in 'year'
    else:
        Ltext = duration + str(time * 2) + ' "months"\n Initial speed: ' + str(round(speed, 3))
        ccolor = color.white
    label(pos=planet.pos, text=Ltext, color=ccolor,
          xoffset=offset * planet.pos.x, yoffset=offset * planet.pos.y)
    ccolor = (0.5 * (1 + random()), random(), random())  # randomise colour of radial vector
    return ccolor


scene = display(title="Kepler's law of equal areas", width=1000, height=1000, range=3.2)
duration = 'Period: '
sun = sphere(color=color.yellow, radius=0.1)  # motion of sun is ignored (or centre of mass coordinates)
scale = 1.0
poss = vector(0, scale, 0)
planet = sphere(pos=poss, color=color.cyan, radius=0.02)

while 1:
    velocity = -vector(0.7 + 0.5 * random(), 0, 0)  # gives a satisfactory range of eccentricities
    ##velocity = -vector(0.984,0,0)   # gives period of 12.0 "months"
    speed = mag(velocity)
    steps = 20
    dt = 0.5 / float(steps)
    step = 0
    time = 0
    ccolor = color.white
    oldpos = vector(planet.pos)
    ccolor = MonthStep(time)
    curve(pos=[sun.pos, planet.pos], color=ccolor)

    while not (oldpos.x > 0 and planet.pos.x < 0):

        rate(steps * 2)  # keep rate down so that development of orbit can be followed
        time += dt
        oldpos = vector(planet.pos)  # construction vector(planet.pos) makes oldpos a varible in its own right
        # oldpos = planet.pos makes "oldposs" point to "planet.pos"
        # oldposs = planet.pos[:] does not work, because vector does not permit slicing
        denom = mag(planet.pos) ** 3
        velocity -= planet.pos * dt / denom  # inverse square law; force points toward sun
        planet.pos += velocity * dt

        # plot orbit
        curve(pos=[oldpos, planet.pos], color=color.red)

        step += 1
        if step == steps:
            step = 0
            ccolor = MonthStep(time)
            curve(pos=[sun.pos, planet.pos], color=color.white)
        else:
            # plot radius vector
            curve(pos=[sun.pos, planet.pos], color=ccolor)

        if scene.kb.keys:
            print
            "key pressed"
            duration = 'Duration: '
            break

    MonthStep(time, 50, 0)
    label(pos=(2.5, -2.5, 0), text='Click for another orbit')
    scene.mouse.getclick()
    for obj in scene.objects:
        if obj is sun or obj is planet: continue
        obj.visible = 0  # clear the screen to do it again
```

I copied Kepler's Laws code in google and compiled it on pycharm.

But there is an error that

**scene = display(title="Kepler's law of equal areas", width=1000, height=1000, range=3.2)**

**TypeError: 'module' object is not callable**

I found some information on google that "pandas" library can improve this error so I tried it but I can't improve this error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "display" with "canvas", which is the correct name of this entity.